# Две ajax-формы

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Есть: форма №1 которая по выбранному значение подтягивает через ajax форму №2.
Проблема: При отправки данных из второй формы они отправляются на url первой формы.
Нужен намёк куда копать.

**UPDATE:**
На всякий случай уточню. Работаю через фреймворк Yii.
1я форма строится методом CHtml::beginForm с указание url. В ней есть только дропдаун список и ajaxButton.
2я форма строится темже методом, с указанием другого url. В ней есть виджет CGridView и ajaxButton.

**UPDATE 2:**
если вторую форму отправлять обычным методом, то работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

По-умолчанию, отправка идет на текущую страницу (контроллер/экшн). Если указано обратное - url в аяксе или sendForm'e, либо action в свойствах формы - отправляется по этому адресу.
Который из них имеет наивысший приоритет - не подскажу. Думаю, ajax>sendForm>action>default

Comment: @knes спасибо. Натолкнули на мысль посмотреть firebug`ом.
$.ajaxSettings.url задан для первой формы. При выводе второй формы ничего не меняется. Сейчас думаю как всё-таки заставить обе формы работать через ajax с разными.  
Пока только мысль отправлять первым параметром строку типа 'showSecondForm','dataSecondForm' и вешать один контролер.  
P.s. буду очень благодарен, если подскажите более разумное и красивое решение.

Answer (score -1):

А для второй формы есть тег <form>? Если да, то вы можете перед отправкой первовой формы на javascript вызывать submit у второй.

Comment: @Drimean поподробней. А то я вас не понимаю.

Comment: Перед отправкой первой формы вызвать на javascript отправку второй формы.

Comment: $("FORM_1").submit(function() {$("#FORM_2").submit();});

Comment: @Drimean я не js-гуру, так что можно ещё подробней? Желательно как маленькому ребёнку.